# R: Find patern and get the values in between

Tags: r, gsub

I am using `readLines()` to extract an html code from a site. In almost every line of the code there is pattern of the form `<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>`. I would like to take the values in between the `<td>`. I tried some compilations such as:

```
output <- gsub(pattern='(.*<td>)(.*)(<td>.*)(.*)(.*<td>)',replacement='\\2',x='<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>')
```

but the output gives back only the one value. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: `gsub('.*<td>(.*)<td>(.*)<td>', '\\1 \\2', '<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>')` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to use this one :`gsub('.*<td>(.*)<td>(.*).*<td>', c('\\1', '\\2'), '<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>') '`  which didnt output the correct answer. Your answer gives an output of length one. Is it possible by `gsub ` to output the result with length two. Yes it could be done later by using for example `strsplit' but i was just wondering if there is an option like this.

Comment: You can just `strsplit(gsub('.*<td>(.*)<td>(.*)<td>', '\\1 \\2', '<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>'), "\\s+")[[1]]`. Though the answer below will be a safer option in case you have more than 2 values

Comment: or may be this `strsplit(string, '<td>')[[1]][-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string <- "<td>VALUE1<td>VALUE2<td>"   

regmatches(string , gregexpr("(?<=<td>)\\w+(?=<td>)" , string , perl = T) )

# use gregexpr function to get the match indices and the lengthes
indices <- gregexpr("(?<=<td>)\\w+(?=<td>)" , string , perl = T)
# this should be the result

# [1]  5 15
# attr(,"match.length")
# this means you have two matches the first one starts at index 5 and the 
#second match starts at index 15

#[1] 6 6
#attr(,"useBytes")
# this means the first match should be with length 6 , also in this case the 

#second match with length of 6

# then get the result of this match and pass it to regmatches function to 
# substring your string at these indices
regmatches(string , indices)
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the "XML" package that can extract tables from HTML?  You probably need to provide more context of the entire message that you are trying to parse so that we could see if it might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually I did tried. But it loads only the first 30 lines of the code. Only with the `readLines` I could get the whole code. Worth mentioning is that when i use `readLines` I have a warning that  'incomplete final line found on www.example.com' . I guess could be a reason why not all the lines are read when using XML package.

Comment: It's more of a comment rather an answer.